# How to access named pipes using JavaScript in Firefox add-on?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, named-pipes

I'm trying to access a named pipe in a Firefox add-on. My code, based on solution 2 to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/553581/NamedplusPipesplusinplusJavascript) CodeProject question, is:

```
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
file.initWithPath("\\\\.\\pipe\\test");
var text = "Some text to be written";
var writer = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream);
// Open file for read/write access, and create it if it does not exist.
writer.init (file, 0x04 | 0x08, -1, 0);
writer.write (text, text.length);
writer.flush ();
writer.close ();
```

When I run this is Firefox Scratchpad, I get:

```
/*
Exception: Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIFileOutputStream.init]
@6
*/
```

Line 6 is the line where I call writer.init.

I've played with passing different flags to writer.init, but no luck. I'm able to write to a normal file path with this code, just not the named pipe path.

I've been searching for more information for most of a day. The only other relevant thing I've found is [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=500151) Bugzilla bug that mentions the same problem, but it's dated 2009.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Edit: Based on the replies I tried the following:

```
var encoder = new TextEncoder();
var array = encoder.encode("This is some text");
var path = "\\\\.\\pipe\\test";
Task.spawn(function() {
    let pfh = yield OS.File.open(path, {write: true});
    yield pfh.write(array);
    yield pfh.close(); 
});
```

which lets me write to a file (if I change the path accordingly) but does not seem to send anything to the pipe.

Here is the (admittedly crude) code I'm using to read the pipe on the .NET side:

```
let server = new NamedPipeServerStream ("\\\\.\\pipe\\test", PipeDirection.InOut)
let reader = new StreamReader (server)
do
    printfn "Listening..."
    server.WaitForConnection ()
    printfn "Connected."
while true do
    while reader.EndOfStream = false do reader.ReadLine () |> printfn "%s"
```

And the code I threw together to verify that I could at least write to the pipe in .NET:

```
let client = new NamedPipeClientStream ("\\\\.\\pipe\\test")
do client.Connect ()
let writer = new StreamWriter (client)
do writer.AutoFlush <- true

// Wait for connection
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep (1000)
let message = "hello"
do message |> writer.WriteLine
```

Comment: After some experimentation I was able to read from a pipe, but writing fails. I'll keep trying. On a side (.net) note, the `NamedPipeClientStream` constructor takes as a parameter the name of the pipe, not the full path.

Comment: Do you still have this need? I now have a lot of experience with `ctypes` and this stuff is easily done in `js-ctypes`

Answer (score -1):

Try OS.File:

```
let encoder = new TextEncoder();                                   // This encoder can be reused for several writes
let array = encoder.encode("This is some text");                   // Convert the text to an array
let promise = OS.File.writeAtomic("\\\\.\\pipe\\test", array,               // Write the array atomically to "file.txt", using as temporary
    {tmpPath: "file.txt.tmp"});                                    // buffer "file.txt.tmp".
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Noitidart. I tried that and it doesn't give me any errors, but I also don't see anything in the pipe. That might be my fault - I'm reading the pipe with .NET's NamedPipeServerStream and maybe I don't have it set up right. I'm about to crash but tomorrow I'll try some alternate methods of reading the pipe and do some reading up on OS.File.

Comment: `writeAtomic` will do a "write to temp, then move/rename/replace" dance. You cannot replace (`MoveFileEX` on Windows IIRC) a named pipe by with a file. ;) The regular `OS.File.open/.write` stuff might work, however. Also, make sure to use the promises correctly, e.g. via [`Task.jsm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Task.jsm).

Comment: Thank you for your reply nmaier. I tried OS.File.write and I was able to write to a file, but again am not seeing anything show up in the pipe. That might still be something I'm doing wrong on the .NET side though. I didn't get to spend as much time as I wanted on this today but will keep playing with it tomorrow.